# Mapping and transferring values of parameters in rows of one dataframe to another dataframe fields in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have two data-frames. One data-frame(df1) has more than 2000 rows, each row having parameters and their values. Other data-frame (df2), I have list of parameters as field names or col headers (fetched from df1). I want to map the values from df1 to df2 and their values are to be stored under each fields respectively in df2.

Example:

```
df1
>     Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5 .......Coln
>     A=5   C=1   E=5   F=4   G=2                   --Row1 
>     A=6   B=3   D=6   E=4   F=4                   --Row2 
>     B=2   C=3   D=3   E=3   F=7                   --Row3
>     A=2   B=3   C=3   D=3   E=7  F=1  G=3         --Row4
```

df2 (This df only have the transposed list of parameters present in df1)

```
   A  B  C  D   E   F   G
```

Desired Output: Values from df1 to be mapped and transferred to df2.
Df2
df2:

```
A  B  C  D   E   F   G
5     1      5   4   2
6  3     6   4   4
   2  3  3   3   7
2  3  3  3   7   1   3
```

Values are to be mapped & transferred from df1 to df2. Df2 has all the parameters. While reading row 1 in df1, whatever parameters matches with with df2 fields then their value will be stored under row 1 of df2.

Answer (score 2):

A solution using [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse). Only the first data frame is needed for this solution.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(Col, Value, -ID, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  separate(Value, into = c("Header", "Value"), sep = "=") %>%
  select(-Col) %>%
  spread(Header, Value) %>%
  select(-ID)
dat2
#      A    B    C    D E F    G
# 1    5 <NA>    1 <NA> 5 4    2
# 2    6    3 <NA>    6 4 4 <NA>
# 3 <NA>    2    3    3 3 7 <NA>
# 4    2    3    3    3 7 1    3
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5 Col6 Col7
    'A=5'   'C=1'   'E=5'   'F=4'   'G=2'  NA     NA                   
    'A=6'   'B=3'   'D=6'   'E=4'   'F=4'  NA     NA                   
    'B=2'   'C=3'   'D=3'   'E=3'   'F=7'  NA     NA               
    'A=2'   'B=3'   'C=3'   'D=3'   'E=7'  'F=1'  'G=3'",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: I asked this question again because I have two data-frames as mentioned above. I have to populate values from one to other. I can't consider one data-frame and resolve this issue. df2 will be used for further analysis. Can you please mention how to populate values from one to other ?

Comment: Looks the same to me. I think after you get `dat2`, you can select the columns in `dat2` based on your `df2`, which should get what you want.

Comment: @rjn_bnf  It looks similar to me as well.  I already showed you how to populate the values from one dataset to another.

Comment: @www, I don't want to select cols in df2. I want to populate everything from df1 to df2. I am preparing a table with values. I collected the parameters (here, A,B,C,D,E, etc ..n) all available in df1 and split them in df2 (horizontally) making them as fields or col headings. Now I have to split their values from df1 to df2. While reading row1 in df1, whatever parameter it will match in df2, their values will be posted in row1 of df2.

Comment: @rjn_bnf Both akrun and I think you asked the same question twice. Perhaps ask a new question with reproducible example and desired output more relevant to your real-world datasets.

Comment: Soon, I will update another post and inform !

Comment: "Error: This function should not be called directly" after running the script

Comment: Did you get the error when running the script on the example dataset or real world dataset?